# construct an MCD (merise) where a table contain columns from the content of another table

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle11g, modeling

i'am facing a problem while trying to make a conception for a school project.and i have two question.

1/
is it possible with oracle to do something like this : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dynamic-columns/

2/
how can i make a modelisation for that with an MCD (method merise ).

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Quote from your link: *"It works by storing a set of columns in a blob and having a small set of functions to manipulate it."*. I don't see an obvious reason why you couldn't write something similar for Oracle (or any other relational database).

Alternatively, take a look at [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), which is a more traditional solution for dynamic columns.

Sorry, I'm not familiar with Merise.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Oracle is not made for creating dynamic columns, but you can do it by using PL/SQL functions (but not while querying with SQL):

```
create or replace procedure add_table_column(table_name varchar2, column_name varchar2, column_type varchar2)
is
 v_script varchar2(4000);
begin
 v_script := 'alter table '||table_name||' add '||column_name||' '||column_type;
 execute immediate v_script;
end;
/
```

You can call it this way:

```
begin
 add_table_column('toto','test','number');
end;
/
```

2/ Merise method is not made for "dynamic objects" as you must begin with a complete data dictionary.

How is your object dynamic, and why do you have to add columns?

You can always get a solution to work by using "regular" tables and relationships.

It sounds like you should start by analyzing the technical implementation in mind. MERISE says to analyze your data model *first* and start to think about technical solutions *after*.